# The server doesn't send data to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a strange problem using ASP.Net WebAPI 2, LINQ and Entity Framework.

When I send a set of data from front-end to back-end, I saw my data in my ViewModel and data mapped to entity correctly. Now when I send the data to database I see my data is empty string and the EF doesn't send any data from back-end to SQL Server. I have attached the SQL Server Profiler's output for the given EF and LINQ code.

Here is my code:

```
using (MyContext dbContext = new MyContext())
{
      var user = dbContext.User
                    .Where(x => x.Username == context.UserName && x.Password == context.Password)
                    .Select(x => new UserClaim()
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Firstname = x.Firstname,
                        Lastname = x.Lastname,
                        Username = x.Username,
                        Roles = x.UserInRoles.Select(u => u.Role.Id).ToList()
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
        {
            //user not found
        }
        //do something...user found!
}
```

Here are my screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's very difficult to diagnose anything without some code.

Comment: Your problem is likely to be fixable, but rather like it would be hard for someone to fix your car without seeing it, we also find it difficult to fix code without seeing it. Please edit your question to include relevant code and, if necessary, sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Please [do not post screen shots of your IDE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode); they include too much useless information and not enough useful information. We can't copy or search for text in screen shots.

Comment: Agreed, no pictures please. It's impossible to copy/paste anything to make a test, or use it in an answer. The resolution also interferes with readability. And lastly it's not searchable by anyone in future. If you can replace the images with proper text then we can start to help. An image of the debug data is probably acceptable, since that's more difficult to capture, but not for the code. Code is text to begin with, it should remain so. Thanks.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check what `context.UserName` and `context.Password` are set to. My money would be on that they are empty strings and that the problem lies more with how you are retrieving those values from the request.  Also, do *not* store passwords in clear text in a database. Store a hash of a password, send passwords to API's over SSL, and hash the password in the API to compare against the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It seems that you have some interceptor that change the query, before sending it to SQL Server. Check to see if you have any class implemented `IDbCommandInterceptor` interface. If yes, check to see what is going to happen in that class?